# What percentage of German masculine nouns are weak nouns?

Tags: noun

Just what the question says. One could restrict the domain of nouns according to a certain frequency or top-X masculine nouns.

Comment: Weak masculine nouns? Schwache, männliche Hauptwörter? Sowas wie Warmduscher? ;)

Comment: siehe [Flexionsklassen](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-N/Texte/Flexionskl.html)

Comment: @userunknown - Danke. Das *Highlight* meines Tages. "Warmduschende Weicheier" könnte krönend konkurrieren.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be a proper scientific approach but it gives you a rough estimate on the occurence.

> Of all 173782 nouns registered in Cannoo.net 3954 nouns belong to the *en/en* inflection class. <sup>[Canoo.net](http://www.canoonet.eu/services/Controller?service=inflectionRules&matchFeatures=%28Cat%20N%29&exclFeatures=%28Plural%20Only%29&matchRules=%28RIRule%20N-Regular%29%28RIRule%20%5BE%5DN/%5BE%5DN%29&inflectionClass=en/en&entryClass=Cat%20N)</sup>.

By definition, all these *"weak"* nouns are masculine. However I have not found the fraction of masculine nouns from all nouns.

Comment: Assuming that 1/3 of all these nouns are masculine (there must be more than that; it has the highest number of nouns in German, no?) there is a weak noun for every other 14 'normal' masculine nouns. Doesn't that make it quite difficult for learners to gobble up all of them?!